# Test class for Error Handler class

Tags: unit-test, error, exception

I have a class for the purpose of handling error. I want to write a test class for the same. Can somebody please help me as I am new to salesforce.
Below is my code of the class.

```
public class ErrorLogHandler{        
   public static void insertHandledExceptions(Exception ex,String objName,String classOrTriggerName,String codeType,String errorRecordId){
        //Checking if Exception is not null
        if (ex != null) {

            //Instantiating error log to insert
            Error_Log__c errorLog = errorlogInit(ObjName,codeType,classOrTriggerName,errorRecordId,null,null,null);

            //Assigning values to fields

            errorLog.Type_of_Exception__c = ex.getTypeName();
            String errDescription = System.Label.error_in + ex.getMessage()+ System.Label.caused_by+ ex.getTypeName();
            errorLog.Error_Message__c = errDescription.length() > 32000 ? errDescription.substring(0, 32000) + ConstantsClass.ABBREVIATE_TEXT  : errDescription;


            if (errorLog != null) {
                try{
                    insert errorLog;
                    if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                        throw new TestException();
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.debug(System.Label.error_in+ e.getMessage());                
                }                
            }                       
        }
    }
 public static void insertHandledSaveExceptions(Database.SaveResult[] lsr,String objName,String classOrTriggerName,String codeType,String errorRecordId){
        List<Error_Log__c> errorLogList = new List<Error_Log__c>();
        //Checking if Exception is not null
        if (lsr != null){         
            //Iterating over SaveResult
            for (Integer i = 0; i < lsr.size(); i++) {        
                Database.SaveResult sr = lsr[i];                                    
                //Checks if records were failed
                if (!sr.isSuccess()) {                    
                Error_Log__c errorLog = errorlogInit(ObjName,codeType,classOrTriggerName,errorRecordId,null,null,null);                 
                errorLog.Error_Message__c = sr.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
                errorLog.Type_of_Exception__c = ConstantsClass.DML_EXCEPTION;
                errorLogList.add(errorLog);                      
                }
            }
        }
        if (errorLogList.size() > 0 ) {     
            try {                
                insert errorLogList;
                if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                    throw new TestException();
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.debug(System.Label.error_in+ e.getMessage());                
          }
        }
    }

public static void insertHandledDeleteExceptions(Database.DeleteResult[] ldr,String objName,String classOrTriggerName,String codeType,String errorRecordId){
        List<Error_Log__c> errorLogList = new List<Error_Log__c>();
        //Checking if Exception is not null
       if (ldr != null) {            
            //Iterating over SaveResult
            for (Integer i = 0; i < ldr.size(); i++) {        
                Database.DeleteResult dr = ldr[i];                                  
                //Checks if records were failed
                if (!dr.isSuccess()) {                    
                Error_Log__c errorLog = errorlogInit(ObjName,codeType,classOrTriggerName,errorRecordId,null,null,null);                 
                errorLog.Error_Message__c = dr.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
                errorLog.Type_of_Exception__c = ConstantsClass.DML_EXCEPTION;
                errorLogList.add(errorLog);                      
                }
            }
        }
        if (errorLogList.size() > 0 ) {     
            try {                
                insert errorLogList;
                if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                    throw new TestException();
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.debug(System.Label.error_in+ e.getMessage());                
          }
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Happy
Can you tell us what exactly error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to be incomplete, but you should be able to test your logger simply by writing unit tests that leverage your code. Here's a basic starting point:

```
@isTest static void testExceptions() {
    try {
        Integer x = 0 / 0;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        ErrorLogHanlder.insertHandledExceptions(e, 'param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4'); // Use real values here
        System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Error_Log__c]);
    }
}

@isTest static void testDmlExceptions() {
    Database.SaveResult[] saveResults = Database.insert(new Account[] { new Account(Name='0'.repeat(300)) }, false);
    ErrorLogHanlder.insertHandledExceptions(saveResults, 'param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4'); // Use real values here
    System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Error_Log__c]);
}
```